# Is it possible to use bag_unpack in Kusto to parse unbounded JSON nesting in Azure LogAnalytics?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

While investigating a deployment failure in Azure using a query below

```
AzureActivity
| where OperationNameValue endswith "XXXXXXXXXXX"
| where ActivityStatus in ("Failed")
| where CorrelationId == "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
| extend p = parse_json(Properties)
| project p
| evaluate bag_unpack(p)
```

I'm getting a result (containing of a `statusMessage` column) that has a very high level of nesting, with the most important message (obviously) at the innermost level.

```
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceOperationFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "ApplianceDeploymentFailed",
        "message": "The operation to create appliance failed. Please check operations of deployment 'app' under resource group '/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/yyy'. Error message: 'At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.'",
        "details": [
          {
            "code": "Conflict",
            "message": "{\r\n \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n \"error\": {\r\n \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n \"details\": [\r\n {\r\n \"code\": \"DeploymentFailed\",\r\n \"message\": \"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.\",\r\n \"details\": [\r\n {\r\n \"code\": \"Conflict\",\r\n \"message\": \"{\\r\\n \\\"status\\\": \\\"Failed\\\",\\r\\n \\\"error\\\": {\\r\\n \\\"code\\\": \\\"ResourceDeploymentFailure\\\",\\r\\n \\\"message\\\": \\\"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\\\",\\r\\n \\\"details\\\": [\\r\\n {\\r\\n \\\"code\\\": \\\"DeploymentFailed\\\",\\r\\n \\\"message\\\": \\\"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.\\\",\\r\\n \\\"details\\\": [\\r\\n {\\r\\n \\\"code\\\": \\\"Conflict\\\",\\r\\n \\\"message\\\": \\\"{\\\\r\\\\n \\\\\\\"status\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"Failed\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\\n \\\\\\\"error\\\\\\\": {\\\\r\\\\n \\\\\\\"code\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"ResourceDeploymentFailure\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\\n \\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\\n \\\\\\\"details\\\\\\\": [\\\\r\\\\n {\\\\r\\\\n \\\\\\\"code\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"DeploymentFailed\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\\n \\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\\n \\\\\\\"details\\\\\\\": [\\\\r\\\\n {\\\\r\\\\n \\\\\\\"code\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"Conflict\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\\n \\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"{\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"status\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Failed\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"error\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": {\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"code\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"ResourceDeploymentFailure\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"details\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": [\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n {\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"code\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"OSProvisioningInternalError\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"OS Provisioning failed for VM 'zzz' due to an internal error: [ProvisionError] cloud-init appears to be running, which is not expected, cannot continue.\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n }\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n ]\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n }\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n}\\\\\\\"\\\\r\\\\n }\\\\r\\\\n ]\\\\r\\\\n }\\\\r\\\\n ]\\\\r\\\\n }\\\\r\\\\n}\\\"\\r\\n }\\r\\n ]\\r\\n }\\r\\n ]\\r\\n }\\r\\n}\"\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n}"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would obviously like to have all errors and details on a single level, with no stringified JSONs in the response.
Is `bag_unpack()` an approriate tool to do that, and what settings I may be missing?
Are there any other functions that can be helpful in dealing with the problem?

Comment: Hi, if the answer below answers your question, please accept it (that's the StackOverflow way of saying Thank You :)). If it doesn't answer your question, please add a comment explaining what else is needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you can have an unlimited amount of nested errors, it's easiest to just use a regex to extract all the error messages using [extract_all()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/extractallfunction):

```
AzureActivity
| where OperationNameValue endswith "XXXXXXXXXXX"
| where ActivityStatus in ("Failed")
| where CorrelationId == "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
| extend Errors = extract_all('"message":"([^"]*)"', tostring(Properties))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only extracts a message with no slashes, and is working with things like this `\\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\\\\\\\"`

Comment: Looks like you need to update the regex to allow backslashes as well, then.

Comment: I asked how to see every error message, together with details, on a single level, representable as a pie or bar chart, with drilldown possibility. I don't see how manually updating regexes helps.

Comment: Finding a better fitting regex can help you extract the all values of "message".